# Count length of sequential consequtive values per group in R

Tags: r, count, data.table, grouping

I have a dataset with consequtive values and I would like to know the count of how many times each length occurs.
More specifically, I want to find out how many id's have a sequence running from 1:2, from 1:3, from 1:4 etc.
Only sequences starting from 1 are of interest.

In this example, id1 would have a "full" sequence running from 1:3 (as the number 4 is missing), id2 has a sequence running from 1:5, id3 has a sequence running from 1:6, id4 is not counted since it does not start with a value of 1 and id 5 has a sequence running from 1:3.

So we end up with two sequences until 3, one until 5 and one until 6.

Is there a clever way to calculate this, without resorting to inefficient loops?

Example data:

```
data <- data.table( id    = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                    value = c(1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,5,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,7))

 > data
    id value
 1:  1     1
 2:  1     2
 3:  1     3
 4:  1     5
 5:  2     1
 6:  2     2
 7:  2     3
 8:  2     4
 9:  2     5
10:  2    10
11:  2    11
12:  3     1
13:  3     2
14:  3     3
15:  3     4
16:  3     5
17:  3     6
18:  4     2
19:  4     3
20:  4     4
21:  4     5
22:  4     6
23:  4     7
24:  4     8
25:  5     1
26:  5     2
27:  5     3
28:  5     7
    id value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table( id    = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                    value = c(1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,5,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,7))

dt[, n := seq_len(.N) - value, by = id]
res <- dt[n == 0, .SD[value == max(value)], by = id][, n := NULL]
head(res)
#>    id value
#> 1:  1     3
#> 2:  2     5
#> 3:  3     6
#> 4:  5     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```r
out <- data[, len0 := rleid(c(TRUE, diff(value) == 1L)), by = .(id) ][
  , .(value1 = first(value), len = .N), by = .(id, len0) ]
out
#       id  len0 value1   len
#    <num> <int>  <num> <int>
# 1:     1     1      1     3
# 2:     1     2      5     1
# 3:     2     1      1     5
# 4:     2     2     10     1
# 5:     2     3     11     1
# 6:     3     1      1     6
# 7:     4     1      2     7
# 8:     5     1      1     3
# 9:     5     2      7     1
```

Walk-through:

- within each `id`, the `len0` is created to identify the increase-by-1 steps
- within `id`,`len0`, summarize with the first value (in case you only want those starting at `1`, see below) and the `len`gth of the run

If you just want to know those whose sequences begin at one, filter on `value1`:

```r
out[ value1 == 1L, ]
#       id  len0 value1   len
#    <num> <int>  <num> <int>
# 1:     1     1      1     3
# 2:     2     1      1     5
# 3:     3     1      1     6
# 4:     5     1      1     3
```

(I think you only need `id` and `len` at this point.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
data[rowid(id)==value, max(value), id]
```

output:

```
   id V1
1:  1  3
2:  2  5
3:  3  6
4:  5  3
```

Comment: Excellent! I believe I had too conservative conditions when thinking about this; i.e. that sequences were not necessarily strictly increasing. Thus, I tried to detect also "trailing" sequences starting with 1 (e.g. `d = data.table(id = 1, value = c(2:3, 1:3))`)...Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One option utilizing `dplyr` might be:

```
data %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(rleid = with(rle(c(0, diff(value)) <= 1), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))) %>%
 filter(rleid == 1 & min(value) == 1) %>%
 summarise(value = paste(value, collapse = "")) %>%
 group_by(value) %>%
 summarise(n = n(),
           ids = toString(id))

  value      n ids  
  <chr>  <int> <chr>
1 123        2 1, 5 
2 12345      1 2    
3 123456     1 3
```

Comment: I've used that `rle` one-liner several times in base R and `dplyr`, for when I don't have `data.table` reliably loaded for its `rleid`. I'm a bit surprised there isn't an analog in the tidyverse, tbh, as its utility is imo fairly high.

Comment: @r2evans Totally agree, a `dplyr/tidyr` equivalent of `data.table::rleid()` would be extremely handy! On the other hand, I think I've seen it discussed by the creators of `tidyverse`, and if I recall it correctly, they said that they don't plan to implement such function.